# Appending an iframe to a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to append an iframe to a nested div, but for some reason, the append doesn't work when it's an iframe.

```
var cmpStyle = "width: " + theWidth + "; height: " + theHeight;
$("#createInMe").append("<div id=\'vid-" + cmpID + "\' 
class=\'videoWrapper\'></div>");
$("#vid-" + cmpID).append("<div id=\'iframe-" + cmpID + "\' 
class=\'videoWrapperIframe\' style=\'" + cmpStyle + "\'></div>");
$("#iframe-" + cmpID).append("<iframe id=\'myId\' width=\'560\' height=\'315\' src=\'https://www.youtube.com/embed/IBvf7KUEZ78\' allowfullscreen=\'true\'></iframe>");
```

The first two divs are created as hoped for, but the iframe does not get created.

I changed it to one string and get the same result in the inspect element window.

```
<div id="createInMe" data-aura-rendered-by="825:0" class="cSaleFunnel" data-aura-class="cSaleFunnel">
    <div class="videoWrapper" id="vid-a1p2a0000005NKEAA2">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: undefined%" class="videoWrapperIframe" id="iframe-a1p2a0000005NKEAA2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**: I believe this has something to do with Salesforce preventing specific types of things from being injectable into the DOM.  The reason that I say that is because of the following code.

```
var bgImage = theResult[i].Image_URL__c;
var cmpStyle = "display: block; width: " + theWidth + "; height: " + theHeight + "; background-image: url(\'" + bgImage + "\')";
$("#createInMe").append("<div id=\'img-" + cmpID + "\' style=\'" + cmpStyle + " \'></div>");


$A.createComponent(
    "aura:HTML", {
        "tag": "div",
        "HTMLAttributes": {
            "id": cmpID,
            "style": cmpStyle
        }
    },
    function(components, status, errorMessage) {
        if (status === "SUCCESS") {
            var body = component.get("v.body");
            body.push(components);
            component.set("v.body", body);
        }
    }
);
```

Now, the createComponent function creates the banner image as hoped for, but the jquery append creates a div with the following style:

```
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 250px;
background-image: url(;
```

It will not add the URL portion, and I tried writing the code in various ways.  Does this mean that the only way to create my nested divs is through createComponent?  And if so, how do I create my nested div with the iframe two divs deep?

Comment: What happens if you use append just once, with all the HTML in one big string?

Comment: @sfdcfox I changed it to a single line and get the same results.  I edited my question to show the output.

Comment: @sfdcfox I updated my question again, as it appears that Salesforce is preventing specific types of appending. I'd love your thoughts on this!

Comment: Okay, I changed the bundle version to 39, and the iframe will append, but the image url still doesn't work...

Comment: Okay, it looks like you've got a quoting issue. One sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apostrophes in the CSS are being misinterpreted. This is a case of not sufficiently escaping quotes; what is happening here is the string is being prematurely terminated, which causes the element to parse incorrectly.

For this reason, I'd recommend using $A.createComponents, which eliminates the possibility that you'll screw up something trivial like this. However, to actually fix this problem, use a template string instead:

```
var cmpStyle = `display: block; width: ${theWidth}; height: ${theHeight}; background-image: url('${bgImage}')`;
$("#createInMe").append(`<div id="img-${cmpID}" style="${cmpStyle}" />`);
```

---

Example code using $A.createComponents:

```
<aura:application >
    <div aura:id="container">

    </div>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
</aura:application>
```

---

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        var cmpID = component.getGlobalId(), cmpStyle = "";
        $A.createComponents(
            [
                ["div",{ id: "vid-"+cmpID, class:"videoWrapper" }],
                ["div",{ id: "iframe-"+cmpID, class: "videoWrapperIFrame", style: cmpStyle }],
                ["iframe",{ id:"myId", width:"560", height:"315", allowfullscreen:"true",
                           src:"https://www.youtube.com/embed/IBvf7KUEZ78" }
                ]
            ],
            (components, status, error) => {
                switch(status) {
                case "DRAFT":
                case "SUCCESS":
                components[0].set("v.body", components[1]);
                components[1].set("v.body", components[2]);
                component.find("container").set("v.body", components[0]);
                break;
                case "ERROR":
                alert(error[0].message);
            }
            });
    }
})
```

Comment: The problem with the createComponents is that I am looping through a related list of records to determine what needs to be created (video, image, text), and I don't see how to use the createComponents with an iframe.  I can't mix and match because I need them to output in a specific order...

Comment: I copied and pasted your cmpStyle string and get the same css results as I did with my string...

Comment: Do you have any references for nesting the iframe 2 divs deep?

Comment: @Logan I added the code I wrote up testing iframes in $A.createComponents to this answer, too.

Comment: You're the best! Really appreciate it!

Comment: @Logan Final note: allowfullscreen seems to be flaky, you might need to find an alternative method for setting that attribute. I'm going to investigate that when I get a moment, but not sure why it's behaving that way.